# (Rails) How to find by id and save users into an instance from another model which has user ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

Apologizes for such a confusing title,

I have 2 models:

User.rb

```
  class User < ApplicationRecord
     devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
     has_many :friends
  end
```

Friend.rb

```
  class Friend < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :user
  end
```

I want to show a list of all friends for a specific user.

Profiles controller:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

def show
end

def followed_users
   @friends = User.where(id: current_user.friends.friend_id)
end

end
```

followed_users.html.erb

```
<% @friends.each do |f| %>
   <%= f.email %>
<% end %>
```

But this doesn't work and I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in ProfilesController#followed_users
undefined method `friend_id' for #       <Friend::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fb960747a90> Did you mean? find_index
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the only thing I need - then I need to display other users by ids (their ids are stored in friend_id attribute of friend model)

Comment: Yeah, then use HABTM like in my answer. Rails does everything for you. No need to do it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
def followed_users
   @friends = User.where(id: current_user.friends.pluck(:friend_id))
end
```

Comment: there's no point trying to recode HABTM when ActiveRecord does it

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Many thanks, Hardik! Can you please also give a link to the detailed explanation, how "pluck" works? I cannot find

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call a column method (accessing the value of a column in the DB) on a whole collection.

Since each user has many friends, `user.friends` returns an association collection (that is, a list) of all the friends the user has.

So `current_user.friends.friend_id` tries to call `friend_id` on some sort of array, and fails. You could just try to `map`, but...

---

There's a much simpler way to do it! Rails can do it for you:

```
def followed_users
   @friends = current_user.friends
end
```

You, however, need a HABTM relationship ("has and belongs to many"). [See the associations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

```
class Friend < ApplicationRecord
 # nothing needed here
 # you need two keys in that table: user_id, friend_id
end
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :friends, class_name: 'User', through: :friends # will pick with user_id
  has_many :befriended, class_name: 'User', through: :friends, foreign_key: 'friend_id' # To find who befriended that user.
end
```